# How does a scintillator work?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering, fluorescence

I am trying to understand how a scintillator works.

Currently my understanding is this:

1. gamma radiation interacts with atom A (through photoelectric absorption or compton scatter) which produces a photoelectron or a Compton scatter electron
2. the photoelectron or compton scatter electron then moves through the fluorescent material interacting with atoms via inelastic interaction (is this just Compton scatter?) causing excitation of an electron in atom B (as well as many others)
3. in atom B the inelastic interaction of the photoelectron or compton scatter electron causes an electron from the valence band to be excited to the conduction band, leaving a hole in the valence band
4. electrons in the conduction band and holes in the valence band of atom B then move to a luminescence centre (is this correct? if so does the whole atom move or just the conduction band electron and the hole?). The impurity atom that creates the luminescence centre I will call atom C.
5. then an electron from the "ground state" of atom C moves to fill the hole in atom B (what does ground state mean here? does it mean K shell electron?) which leaves a hole in an inner shell of atom C
6. the excited electron from atom B (the one in the conduction band) then moves to atom C, initially it is located in the "excited state" (not sure where this is, is it the conduction band of atom C?) but quickly falls to the hole in the inner shell of atom C
7. as the energy level of the inner shell of the impurity is less than the energy level of the conduction band electron, this energy must be released as the electron falls. It is released as electromagnetic radiation in the visible light spectrum, and the exact wavelength (and therefore colour of the light) will depend on the energy difference between the conduction band of atom B and the k shell of atom C?

I have no background in physics, I apologise for any mistakes and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point out where I am wrong. Also any YouTube video recommendations to understand this better would be appreciated. I need to sit the Fellow of the Royal College of Radiologists [FRCR Part 1](https://www.rcr.ac.uk/clinical-radiology/examinations/frcr-part-1-radiology-cr1) exam in February, so any recommendations specific to this would be great! I find [Farrs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780702028441/farrs-physics-for-medical-imaging-second-edition) difficult to understand and [Crack the Core](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Crack_the_Core_Exam.html?id=WShBvgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) didn't go into this level of detail.

Comment: The physics described in the question does suggest that it is about inorganic scintillators and is a duplicate. If information about plastic and and liquid organic scintillators is also desired, the question could be edited to make this clear. You might want to check out the  ["Seeing the light"](https://indico.cern.ch/event/518648/) from Fermilab, which is a nice lecture (with both video and slides) on the basics of both inorganic and organic scintillators.